# Find and Replace using sed, awk or grep

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

How can I find the word "UP" and replace it with "DOWN" in below data using sed, awk or grep?

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "API Dev :: UP";
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "API QA :: UP";
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "API Reg :: UP";
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = "API Prod :: UP";
```

I am looking to find/replace one line at a time. Something like using `for loop` and then find/replace one line after other.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain `one line at a time`

Answer (score 1):

This is sed 101:

```
sed 's/:: UP/:: DOWN/'
```

Comment: how can we find/replace one line after the other, but not all line at the same time.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  It will be slow.

Comment: If I put above line in my script, it would replace all lines at once         `URL=`grep "document.getElementById" index.html | awk -F' ' '{print $7}'`

for var in $URL
do
        SERVICE_STATUS=`curl -s --head $URL | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`
                if [[ $SERVICE_STATUS -eq "200" ]]
                then
                        `sed 's/:: UP/:: DOWN/' index.html`
                fi
done`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo line | sed 's/UP/DOWN/'
```

Where line is the string you want to replace

Answer (score 0):

While @john-zwinck's answer gives you the solution for this, if you want to have a more restricted pattern, do something like below

```
 sed -E 's/(API[[:blank:]]*[[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]*::[[:blank:]]*)UP/\1DOWN/'
                                                                    filename
```

which will give you

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "API Dev :: DOWN";
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "API QA :: DOWN";
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "API Reg :: DOWN";
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = "API Prod :: DOWN";
```